# How to count the results with autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to count the results that show in the autocomplete.

HTML the input field:

```
<input name="input_1" id="input_1_1" 
type="text" value="" class="medium ui-autocomplete- input" 
tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">
```

Jquery autocomplete:

```
var availableTags = [];
$("#toggles h3").each(function() {
    availableTags.push( $(this).text());    
  });
   // console.log( + " availableTags items gevonden"); 
    console.log(availableTags);
 $( ".autocomplete #input_1_1" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
```

Jquery count code:

```
var actualTags = (".ui-menu-item"); 
console.log(actualTags);
$(".autocomplete #input_1_1").keyup(function(){
 $(".count").text(actualTags.length +" results");
});
```

`ui-menu-item` is the class of every result in the autocomplete.
.count = the class of the `<p>` where the counter must be.

I just want to have the third code to count the results that are shown in the textbox while typing. This seems to work but it counts the wrong items, i don't know which item i should type here; var actualTags = (".ui-menu-item"); it now gives all the availableTags in the textbox (even the ones that not show up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

items are appended as li in `.ui-autocomplete`.Try this:

```
 $(".count").text($('.ui-autocomplete > li').length +" results");
```

also its better to use native option `open` of autocomplete to ensure that length is count only after options are added:

```
$( ".autocomplete #input_1_1" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
open: function(event,ui){
   $(".count").text($('.ui-autocomplete > li').length +" results");
 }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/282/)**

Comment: Ty but i get the exact same result as my own code. But i knwo what it does now i putted in console.log(actualTags) and it counts the letters . var actualTags = (".ui-menu-itemdwdwdwdw");  shows 21 in the count (<p>)

Answer (score 1):

Better option is to go with [**`response`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) callback provided by jQuery autocomplete

> **Triggered after a search completes**, before the menu is shown. Useful
>   for local manipulation of suggestion data, where a custom source
>   option callback is not required. This event is always triggered when a
>   search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are
>   no results or the Autocomplete is disabled.

**Code:**

```
$(".autocomplete #input_1_1").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        response: function (event, ui) {
            $(".count").text(ui.content.length);
        }
    });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6GPec/)